# c# populate list<T> from two arrays or delimited strings

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two arrays populated from strings:

```
public partial class tarBuyInternet
{
    public string desc { get; set; }
    public string param { get; set; }
}

public List<tarBuyInternet> listTarBuyInternet;

// …

string[] descs;
string[] prms;

descs = jarrObj1["desc"].ToString().Split(GlobalClass.strDelimiter);
prms = jarrObj1["params"].ToString().Split(GlobalClass.strDelimiter);
```

How can I populate properties of `List<TarBuyInternet>` with corresponding array? Or how to populate list directly from string splitting it to corresponding property?

Comment: Provide example of your string, it seems that you only need to iterate with good old for loop, but your code suggest that you split the string and get two arrays with your values.

Comment: It's a usual C# convention that class and property names should use UpperCamelCase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the extension method [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) to walk the two arrays in parallel and create a `tarBuyInternet` for each pair:

```
var listTarBuyInternet = descs.Zip(prms, (d, p) => new tarBuyInternet { desc = d, param = p }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just loop through the arrays, and add to the list (provided that the arrays have the same length):

```
for (var i=0; i<descs.Length; i++){
  listTarBuyInternet.Add(new tarBuyInternet{
     desc = descs[i];
     param = prms[i];
  });
}
```

---

Since there is a discussion that this cannot be done in linq, here's a monstrosity that will get the job done (even without using `Zip`, which is the correct answer here):

```
var result = 
      from d in descs.Select((item, index) => new {item, index})
      join p in prms.Select((item, index) => new {item, index}) 
      on d.index equals p.index
      select new tarBuyInternet{desc = d.item, param = p.item};
listTarBuyInternet = result.ToList();
```

Comment: I think that it should be: for (var i=0, i<=descs.Length - 1; i++)

Answer (score 2):

@Kajal Sinha
Well no, you actually can.

Edit @SWeko: You are right, my bad. THis however should work ^^

```
listTarBuyInternet = jarrObj1["desc"].ToString().Split(GlobalClass.strDelimiter)
            .Zip(jarrObj1["params"].ToString().Split(GlobalClass.strDelimiter),
            (d, p) => new tarBuyInternet { desc = d, param = p }).ToList();
```

Should work.

Comment: you are doing the same thing what I said in my post. you need to learn the internals of linq. Do not downvote answers by just being biased to your answer.

Comment: This will actually create a Carthesian product of the lists, i.e. of you have 15 `desc` and 15 `param` strings, you'll get a list of 225 `tarBuyInternet` items

Comment: No, you stated that you "cannot" populate the list directly from the splits. That's just wrong. Of course you need to iterate over the arrays, but your answer was clearly misleading.

Answer (score 0):

As your question seems like you are asking the C# compiler to automatically populate the list by directly injecting the splitted array somehow, you need to tell the compiler how to read from array and assign property values. You need to iterate over to create tarBuyInternet instances and then add those instances to the listTarBuyInternet.

Comment: There are at least two answers that directly contradict that :)

Comment: My answer is more inclined to Or how to populate list directly from string splitting it to corresponding property? By directly I understand either through constructor or assigning array to property which is not possible. LINQ is just a syntactic sugar over iteration which I have already indicated.